# reindexing dataframes replaces all my data with NaNs, why?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

So I was investigating how some commands from Pandas work, and I ran into this issue; when I use the reindex command, my data is replaced by NaN values. Below is my code:

```
>>>import pandas as pd

>>>import numpy as np

>>>frame1=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(365))
```

then, I give it an index of dates:

```
>>>frame1.index=pd.date_range(pd.datetime(2017, 4, 6), pd.datetime(2018, 4, 5))
```

then I reindex:

```
>>>broken_frame=frame1.reindex(np.arange(365))
```

aaaand all my values are erased. This example isn't particularly useful, but it happens any and every time I use the reindex command, seemingly regardless of context. Similarly, when I try to join two dataframes:

```
>>>big_frame=frame1.join(pd.DataFrame(np.arange(365)), lsuffix='_frame1')
```

all of the values in the frame being attached (np.arange(365)) are replaced with NaNs before the frames are joined. If I had to guess, I would say this is because the second frame is reindexed as part of the joining process, and reindexing erases my values.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 7):

[***From the Docs***](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

> Conform DataFrame to new index with optional filling logic, ***placing NA/NaN in locations having no value in the previous index***. A new object is produced unless the new index is equivalent to the current one and copy=False

Emphasis my own.

You want either `set_index`

```
frame1.set_index(np.arange(365))
```

Or do what you did in the first place

```
frame1.index = np.arange(365)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I don't quite understand what the part you emphasize means, though. "Placing NaNs in locations having no value in the previous index" doesn't seem applicable to me because all my locations have values in them before reindexing. It also doesn't help  explain the .join() issue.

Thanks again!

Comment: @Jacob your question was "Why does reindexing replace with NaNs?".  The emphasized text is the explanation of why.  It was explicitly designed to do so.  So your question is exactly answered in the documentation.  However, I am guessing that `reindexing` **isn't** what you want.  And that you actually want `set_index`

Answer (score 2):

I did not find the answer helpful in relation to what I think the question is getting at so I am adding to this.

The key is that the initial dataframe **must have the same index** that you are reindexing on for this to work. **Even the names must be the same!** So if you're new MultiIndex has no names, your initial dataframe must also have no names.

```
m = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['col'].unique(), 
                                pd.date_range(df.date.min(), 
                                              df.date.max() + 
                                              pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1), 
                                              freq='M')])
df = df.set_index(['col','date']).rename_axis([None,None])
df.reindex(m)
```

Then you will preserve your initial data values and reindex the dataframe.